# Better many to many filtering logic

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have 2 models like this:

```
class ModelA(AbstractUser):
    is_author = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    user = models.ForignKey(ModelA, ondelete=models.CASCADE)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, blank=True)
    date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Right now, let's say I wanted only all ModelB objects liked by the logged-in user, I would do something like this in my view:

```
def view_funct(request):
    user = request.user
    modelb_objects = ModelB.objects.filter(liked=user).order_by("-date")
```

This works, however, I feel like there is better and faster filtering I don't know of yet. Is there?

Comment: `.filter(liked=user)` how does that work? `liked` is a `BooleanField` and `user` is an instance of the user model so you should be getting an error there.

Comment: Yeah... I made an error as I wrote the model directly here and mistakenly wrote a BooleanField instead of a ManyToManyField I intended to write. I have made the correction now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works, however, I feel like there is better and faster filtering I don't know of yet. Is there?

This *is* implemented efficiently. A database will construct *indices* for columns that have a `ForeignKey`, to retrieve related objects in an efficient way. When you filter with:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(liked=user).order_by('-date')
```

then this will run a query with:

```
SELECT appname_modelb.*
FROM appname_modelb
INNER JOIN appname_modelb_liked.model_b_id = appname_modelb
WHERE appname_modelb_liked.user_id = id_of_user
ORDER BY appname_modelb.date DESC
```

You can probably slightly boost efficiency by adding an index on the `date` field to do the ordering step more efficient:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    user = models.ForignKey(ModelA, ondelete=models.CASCADE)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, blank=True)
    date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when writing the models initially as I just wrote the models directly here as an example and not that I copied a model from elsewhere. I have made the correction to reflect the exact question I intended to ask.

Comment: @SajereKells: normally the item in the question will work fast, since the database will define a B-tree index on the junction table.

Comment: So, do you mean the filtering I currently use for cases like the one in question is ideal?

Comment: @SajereKells: yes, you can boost the efficiency slighly by adding a database index on the `date` field, since this will order more effectively.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot.